# Type for parameter in TypeScript Arrow Function

Tags: typescript

With

```
"noImplicitAny": true
```

TypeScript will give the error:

*Parameter 'x' implicitly has an 'any' type*

for

```
.do(x => console.log(x));
```

and error

*',' expected*

for:

```
.do(x: any => console.log(x));
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After some searching I found the correct way to define a type for the parameter is to add parentheses:

```
.do((x: any) => console.log(x));
```