# How can I declare interface in array of object?

Tags: typescript

What I am trying here is to declare an interface in my variable with array of object. How to declare interface in that situation? If I declare my variable as any it works fine.

```
export interface mWeather
{
    date: Date;
    temperatureC: number;
    tempartureF: number;
    summary: string;
}

weatherinfo: mWeather [] = [];
//weatherinfo: any = {}; This line works fine.

getWeatherInfo(){
   this.http.get(url).subscribe(response:(how can I declare type here too)=> 
   
   this.weatherinfo = response);
}
```

If I declare weatherinfo: any = {}; then it works fine.

My data:

```
[
    {
        "date": "2023-05-20",
        "temperatureC": 54,
        "temperatureF": 129,
        "summary": "Hot"
    },
    {
        "date": "2023-05-21",
        "temperatureC": 34,
        "temperatureF": 93,
        "summary": "Scorching"
    },
    {
        "date": "2023-05-22",
        "temperatureC": 8,
        "temperatureF": 46,
        "summary": "Chilly"
    },
    {
        "date": "2023-05-23",
        "temperatureC": -19,
        "temperatureF": -2,
        "summary": "Hot"
    },
    {
        "date": "2023-05-24",
        "temperatureC": 34,
        "temperatureF": 93,
        "summary": "Bracing"
    }
]
```

Comment: Arrow functions require brackets around parameters to declare the type `(s: string) => s.toUpperCase()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type for parameter in TypeScript Arrow Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36245387/type-for-parameter-in-typescript-arrow-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the [`HttpClient.get()` method #Overload 15](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get). Your code should be as below:

```
getWeatherInfo(){
  this.http.get<mWeather[]>(url).subscribe((response: mWeather[])=> {
   
     this.weatherinfo = response;
  });
}
```

Comment: No need to use type in the callback anymore.